# Spark Data Frame Generate Sequence Number starts with a specified value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to generate the sequence number in DataFrame starts with a specified value.
I am able to generate asequence number in DataFrame 1. How ever when i am trying to append a new data frame i would like to get the DataFrame 1 max sequence value and generate the new Sequence number in DataFrame 2 starts with the max value from DataFrame1.

Comment: write a udf for the problem.

Comment: Can you please throw more details on this? if i write a UDF how i can pass the previous value to the UDF and also how multiple executors will make sure the same number is not generating at a time? Can you please share if you have any